# How to extract the \includegraphics command in tikzscale package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, auto-pst-pdf

I just started using the `tikzscale` package for loading and correctly resizing tikz pictures. The problem is that the package replaces the original `\includegraphics` command with its own procedures to make loading of different file formats consistent. However, I think this might lead to compatibility problems with other packages since I get error loading these two packages together but each one works fine separately.

My question is how I can only call the `\includegraphics` command from tikzscale package when I want to load a tikz picture, but for the rest of figures I use the original `\includegraphics` ? Can I somehow define a command to load tikz pictures with tikzscale function while leaving the original  command intact?
I tried with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Actually the package does exactly the converse: it replaces `\includegraphics` with its own version everywhere *except* in a `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: AFAIK the "old" `\includegraphics` is used if the extension of the graphic being included is `.png` or `.pdf` or `.jpg`, so no incompatibility is created (unless you have a tikz picture with the same filename).

Comment: I am experiencing problem using psfrag with auto-pst-psf and declare the extensions by \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}. For loading normal figures (not tikz) If all the files are in the working folder everything is fine, but if relative addresses are used  e.g. \graphicspath{{../fl1/fl2/}}, Then it returns an error. if I remove tikzscale package then it works fine.