# \includegraphics from tikzscale spitting out garbled paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikzscale

I want to include an external tikz-file scaled to size with tikzscale via its version of \includegraphics. However, on top of the picture a lot of garbled paths appear:
[image]

It looks like \includegraphics tries to guess subpaths (which don´t exist), but somehow prints them. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\graphicspath{{fig/auxiliary/}, {fig/Matlab/}, {fig/Visio/},
{fig/other/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbhp]
\includegraphics{fig/figure1.tikz}
\caption{a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The content of windquiver.tikz is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `1.1*\figureheight` looks to be in error (there should be no `*` ) although I wouldn't expect it to have that effect but without a real example impossible to debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your guess. Had already tried it with values like 15cm. Also have used it in this form in other reports before successfully...

Comment: ['... without a real example impossible to debug.'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315167/includegraphics-from-tikzscale-spitting-out-garbled-paths#comment768997_315167)

Comment: Finally singled out the error. It was a wrong `\graphicspath` hidden in the depths of the template. Updated the question - please feel free to edit it to make it useful to others.

Comment: @PaulGaborit thanks for the tip. It is wrong though - tikzscale actually depends on this.

Comment: @PaulPaulsen IMHO, the patch made by `tikzscale` on `\includegraphics` is a very bad design: you can't use usual `graphicx` keys (as `angle`) with a TikZ picture.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Well, I certainly don´t know enough about design principles to be able to judge that, but I can see why changing an existing command without need instead of supplying a new one would be a bad idea. However, I like what the package does, so I need to cope with it. Also, I am unsure about how the patch changes the behaviour for other file types than .tikz: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91334/how-to-extract-the-includegraphics-command-in-tikzscale-package#comment197345_91334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by `\graphicspath`. Like @Dzaic pointed out in a comment, you must not use commata between different paths in the argument of `\graphicspath`. If you change the MWE to the following form, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\graphicspath{{fig/auxiliary/}{fig/Matlab/}{fig/Visio/}{fig/other/}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbhp]
\includegraphics{fig/windquiver.tikz}
\caption{a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am not sure though if all the subdirectories will be looked up for graphics or only the last one. Also note that obviously the graphics paths don´t work - check this question and answer: [How to use \graphicspath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139401/41356)

Comment: @PaulGaborit I am sorry that I mixed up the filenames. Changed it back into windquiver.tikz. However, it does compile without any problems on my machine. You have to make sure the tikz file is in the right subdir (/fig in this case) though.

Comment: According to the documentation the notation should be without comma: `\graphicspath{{fig/auxiliary/}{fig/Matlab/}{fig/Visio/}{fig/other/}}`

Comment: @PaulGaborit I am sorry, I don´t know why it doesn´t compile in your case. Please feel free and have a look at the tikzscale documentation or at one of the questions here related to this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215557/41356, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252992/41356 and so on...

Comment: @Dzaic thanks for the addition. I updated the answer.

Comment: @PaulGaborit did you get it to compile?

Comment: Also worth noting that when using `\includegraphics` for a tikz file via `tikzscale`, the extension (`.tikz`) is optional but not optional when the path to the file contains a slash.